# RESTful and HTML content

Tags: spring, alfresco

I've an issue with a RESTful call. Alfresco returns to my Spring code this XML

```
<questions>
    <question>
        <name>INTRO</name>
        <title>Intro</title>
        <subtitle>Let's start the test!</subtitle>
        <content><p>Welcome!</p></content>
        <type>NORESPONSE</type>
    </question>
</questions>
```

with this call

```
Questions questionList = (Questions) restTemplate.getForObject(webScriptUrl, Questions.class, params);
```

The content property of my bean is always empty; I'm quite sure the problem is related to the html tag because all other properties are correclty filled. How can I tell to marshaller to consider  tag something that contains HTML code?

thanks,
Andrea

Comment: I don't know anything about the mashaller, but did you try putting your HTML in a CDATA node within the content element ?

Comment: I solved adding to FreeMaker ${firstName?html} escaping to alfresco response template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using ${firstName?html} escaping on Alfresco response template.

http://www.freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_escape.html